# Mockito Error in test case while sending message to activeMQ onMessage()

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, activemq-classic

Iam writing an application using ActiveMQ and unit test cases using Mockito where i have a asynchronous onMessage() listener and a method to test the same.The test case fails if i add any if condition in the onMessage().How to avoid this

The code snippet is as below

**Main.java**

```
//Initialize boolean here
    boolean flag=false;

    public void onMessage(final Message message) {

                    //getting error in the below if condition
                    if(flag) //Not executing at all Null pointer here
                    {
                            if (!(message instanceof TextMessage)) {
                               //Log error
                            }
                            try {
                                final String messageType = message.getStringProperty("messageType");
                                _LOG.info("The MessageType is {}", messageType);
                                final String msg = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
                                _LOG.debug(msg);
                            } catch (final JMSException e) {
                                _LOG.error("We could not read the message", e);
                            }
                    }
                    else  //not able to execute if or else conditions
                    {
                        //do Something else
                    }
               }
```

**MockTest.java**

```
        //Call Main here
         @InjectMocks
         private Main listener;

        @Test
            public void shouldProcessMessage() throws JMSException {

                final String messageType = "Hello";
                final String messageBody ="Hi";
                final ActiveMQTextMessage message = new ActiveMQTextMessage();
                message.setStringProperty("messageType", messageType);
                message.setText(messageBody);

                // The below line does not execute at all
                // iam getting null pointer exception here
                listener.onMessage(message);
            }
```

Comment: Where the heck is `flag` coming from?

Comment: flag == true? If it's a boolean don't compare to true. If it's a Boolean you probably want a boolean. Seems like an unboxing error nothing to do with mockito or activemq.

Answer (score 0):

Has the Boolean value `flag` been instantiated somewhere in this class?

If you are getting an NPE, it's probably because you have not instantiated the `flag` variable.

Comment: i have updated the Main.java, flag is a boolean variable which is instantiated in Main.java